# Wanted: Linux-friendly AM4 motherboard, multiple M.2 slots, without Realtek

Tags: motherboard, ryzen

An upgrade of another PC left me w/ components to reuse in this PC. I'd like to think before buying.

I need an AM4 socket motherboard, and want a Linux-friendly (Debian family) build for virtualization, to enable opening Win10 from within Linux. I want [IOMMU](https://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/9-bios/215--enable-iommu-or-vt-d-in-your-motherboard-bios.html) and all OS used will be 64-bit. Here's the hardware I wish to reuse in that motherboard:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X
RAM: 2 each 16GB DIMMs, DDR4 3200, dual Kingston, dual rank
GPU: GTX 1080
SSD: M.2, 2 each NVMe, 1 TB
PSU: 680W
Case: Spacious ATX

Everything I could find by searching Amazon and Newegg for an x470 OR x570 motherboard reveal no Linux driver support from the manufacturer; Realtek drivers are a massive recurring pain, quite frequently, over at https://askubuntu.com and I definitely wish to avoid Realtek LAN and WiFi.

Finding drivers for Linux are the eternal problem as most motherboard manufacturers do not provide them, and review sites such as [KitGuru](http://www.kitguru.net/reviews/?category_name=motherboard) don't discuss Linux, only Windows.

Does any AM4 motherboard have manufacturer support for Linux?

Comment: You only need to worry about IOMMU support if you want to run games with good graphics performance in the Windows 10 VM. IOMMU is a feature that allows a VM to "see" hardware in the host system, and therefore use it as if it were physically installed in the *virtual* system. However, booting the Windows 10 OS inside a VM from its own NVMe drive may require IOMMU, it depends on a lot of specific configuration details.

Comment: There are quite a few AM4 boards that have Intel NICs, but AFAIK, all of them have Realtek audio. You could always use a PCIe sound card. Probably easier than searching for that unicorn motherboard.

Comment: @MechEng, point well taken, so adjusting my sails for a slightly different tack. Thank you!

Comment: If you use a USB DAC or soundcard you can rely on good support for linux because all USB soundcards use [USB Audio Device Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Audio_streaming). I believe the linux kernel itself comes with drivers for USB soundcards and audio frameworks like Pulseaudio, ALSA, Jack, etc. are all compatible with that driver. A standalone USB soundcard can easily be better quality than the built-in audio anyways!

Comment: Likewise for PCIe ethernet devices, Windows has a term called "Plug and Play" which refers to basic built-in drivers for the most essential devices like soundcards, ethernet, wifi, etc. Linux would have this same sort of baseline support for various devices included in the kernel but hardware-specific features and settings are only controlled by the OEM's driver.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the ASUS B450-F for my last Ubuntu build. It was originally a R7 1700x on an ASUS B350-F, then I later swapped it for a R7 2700x on an ASUS B450-F. No issues with either board.

Specifications: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-F-GAMING/specifications/

Comment: do you use virtualization on that upgraded PC, and run Win10 from within Linux? Do you use IOMMU?

Comment: No, that specific build did not require any virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

Any X-series board really works for you on top of the 2 gen, most have more than 1 m.2 port in case you need more you can use one of the PCI ports with which you can have up to 2 SSD M.2

Comment: Thank you for that observation. However, I've learned more, and need to rephrase the question to avoid problems I now know I want to avoid.