# I have a question about bandwidth and the key differences between PCI express versions

Tags: processor, pcie

I'm building my first gaming pc, and I have a question about PCI express versions. I'm looking to purchase a CPU for a budget system. I'm torn between two of them, the AMD Ryzen 5 2600, and the 3400g. From what I've researched, the 2600 is faster, put it has one problem. It only has PCI express 3.0, instead of the newer 4.0. I did the research, and PCIe 4.0 has double the bandwidth. I use wireless connection for my internet. Can someone explain this to me? Do I need double the Bandwidth or is it just a nice perk to have? Much appreciated.

Comment: The PCIe bandwidth is a very different bandwidth than your uplink/wifi bandwidth. The PCIe is far bigger, and being one of them larger or smaller practically does not affect the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the foreseeable future, in an entry-level personal computer, PCIe 4.0 is rather nice-to-have instead of a must-have. Or to put it differently: there are much better ways to spend excess budget than on this feature. more RAM, (larger) SSD, faster CPU, faster GPU, you name it.
Very few devices benefit from the increased bandwidth in a way that would be noticeable to the end-user. WiFi is definitely not one of them, the bandwidth here is not even close to saturating PCIe 3.0 links.
You also would need a PCIe 4.0 capable motherboard to unlock this feature. So far, only X570 motherboards have PCIe 4.0 in the consumer space. And these are way to expensive to be justified in a budget PC.
In addition to that, a Ryzen 3400G does not even have PCIe 4.0. The Ryzen 3000 APUs are still based on the Zen1 architecture, hence only PCIe 3.0.

Comment: I am shopping https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12943/wanted-linux-friendly-am4-motherboard-multiple-m-2-slots-without-realtek myself, and X570 motherboards start at $200 and get much more expensive quickly; hardly 'budget' territory. Spend the difference on NVMe/PCIe SSDs instead of SATA-III.

Comment: Why are you repeating what I just wrote? X570 being too expensive for a budget build was exactly the point I made in my answer. In addition to explaining that excess budget should be spent on other things. I explicitly named SSD storage as an example.